# Posting testresults to an API after all the testcases has run

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I'm trying to use Xray's API to post the results from my unit tests.
I want the method for posting the results to be ran after all my tests are finished up running (then I have a xml-file with the results I want to post).

but I'm not sure if I've understood how the mechanics work - it looks like the teardown gets executed after every single test.

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. Create a method that will execute ONCE after all tests are done, which should post the generated xml-file with test-results to an external API.

   ```
   [TestFixture]
   public class ProjectEmailAgentUnitTests
    {
       private ProjectEmailAgent _emailAgent;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
     {
        _emailAgent = new ProjectEmailAgent();

    }

    [Test, Property("Requirement", "IUV-23")]
    [TestCase(" ", false)]
    [TestCase("mcp a", false)]
    [TestCase("mc pa", false)]
    [TestCase("mcpa", true)]
    public void isKeyWordExisting(string subject, Boolean expected)
    {
        Assert.That(_emailAgent.isKeyWordExisting(subject), Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }

        [TearDown]
        public async Task TestTearDown(){
        var fileName = "filename.xml";
        var fileName2 = "xray.json";
        var url = "https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v1/import/execution/nunit/multipart";
        using (var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("NKdKd9Yk"))
        {
            formContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
            // 3. Add the filename C:\\... + fileName is the path your file
            Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:/test/Projects/ProjectEmailAgentTest/bin/Debug/net6.0/TestResults/" + fileName);
            formContent.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), fileName, fileName);
            Stream fileStream2 = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:/test/Projects/ProjectEmailAgentTest/" + fileName2);
            formContent.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream2), fileName2, fileName2);


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Bearer Token header if needed
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "token");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));

                try
                {
                    // 4.. Execute the MultipartPostMethod
                    var message = await client.PostAsync(url, formContent);
                    // 5.a Receive the response
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Do what you want if it fails.
                    throw ex;
                }
    }
   ```

Comment: There are many ways to run NUnit tests, for example, nunit3-console.exe, Visual Studio test explorer, etc. Please indicate how you are running your tests in order to make it possible to give an answer.

Comment: @Charlie sorry for not mentioning. At the moment I'm just running them inside Visual Studio Code (Run tests in context).

Comment: Seems like I'm able to achieve what I want if I use the [order(n)] attribute, and specify my teardown as a [Test]. Not really what I want, as this method will be a part of the testresults, but at least it gets executed in the way I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give an answer... but first this...

> I think it's actually a mistake to use code *in your tests* to manage the reporting *of the tests*. That's because NUnit, like most test frameworks, works really hard to segregate the tests from the context in which they are run. However, as you have shown, it can be made to work. What's questionable is how long it will keep working. Given that the NUnit folks are trying hard to isolate tests from their context, suppose they make improvements in the next release - what happens then? Those improvements would appear to you as bugs, because you are relying on running a certain lack of isolation.

However, with the current state of the nunti framework, if you want to do this,
use an assembly-level `SetUpFixture`. Specifically...

1. Create a class in the global namespace, i.e. outside all namespaces.
2. Decorate that class with `[SetUpFixture]`
3. Within the class, add a `public void` method and decorate it with `[OneTimeTearDown]`.

Now you have a class that looks something like this...

```
[SetUpFixture]
public static class MySetUpFixture
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public static void AfterAllTestsRun()
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

As stated above place this outside of any namespaces. I made my class static. It doesn't have to be but **do not** let any of your test fixtures inherit from it. You'll confuse NUnit if you do.

---

On the other hand, if you want to do this outside of your test code, write a program to read the TestResult file and create the necessary email. It's not that hard to do.

Comment: first and foremost. Thanks a a lot for the explanation. I'm not seeing how I can create a program/code that'll pick up when my tests have ran, then make an API call and post the generated results. I have created a simple bash-script that'll post my results to the API, but that needs to be triggered manually - not seeing how I can automate the execution of the script after tests have been ran. The only solution I can really come up with, is to create a pipeline and report the results from the pipeline, instead of using the API-endpoint.

Comment: Yes, having some sort of script is exactly what I meant. That way, you would not have emails sent every time somebody ran the tests locally - only when the script was run, which included the email option.